# Drawbacks of the `H` specifier

Tags: floats, positioning

According to the [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package documentation, the `H` float placement specifier

> [...]when added to a float, tells LaTeX to “put the float HERE,
>   period”. If there isn’t enough space left on the page, the float is
>   carried over to the next page together with whatever follows, even
>   though there might still be room left for some of that.

I've heard some opinions in favour and some against the use of this placement specifier. I personally tend not to recommend its use and suggest the use of an static object from the beginning instead (but the only reason I have is that I don't like the idea of declaring something as a float and then suppressing the flotation; I'd rather use a static object from the beginning).

Are there any major drawbacks associated with the `H` float placement specifier besides the one mentioned in the last sentence of the quoted text?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one drawback, that stems from the fact that `[H]` floats are set as a `minipage`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\pangram}{The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\pangram

\begin{figure}[h]
  \pangram
  \caption{\pangram}
\end{figure}

\pangram

\clearpage
\pangram

\begin{figure}[H]
  \pangram
  \caption{\pangram}
\end{figure}

\pangram

\end{document}
```

Another drawback is the way it handles "in-text floats":

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\newcommand{\pangram}{The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog.}
\begin{document}
\pangram
\begin{figure}[h]
  \pangram
  \caption{\pangram}
\end{figure}
\pangram

\clearpage
\pangram
\begin{figure}[H]
  \pangram
  \caption{\pangram}
\end{figure}
\pangram

\end{document}
```

Comment: “The quick fox jumped over the lazy dog” isn't a pangram.  the conventional version has a “quick _brown_ fox”, but i think there are other versions.

Comment: @wasteofspace Even with brown, it's not a pangram. Either jump has to be in the present tense, or you need more than 1 dog.

Comment: So there's no additional *major* drawbacks after all?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: You've already mentioned another one in your original post: "If there isn’t enough space left on the page, the float is carried over to the next page together with whatever follows, even though there might still be room left for some of that." I think the consensus about `[H]` is that it goes against what floats should do... float. But, if well-used under these circumstances, there is no *major* drawback.

Comment: Yes, that's why I said "additional". I guess you're right; well used it can be helpful in some circumstances.

Answer (score 6):

Another drawback is that using the `H` modifier for *some* floats might result in floats out of order, as the following example demonstrates:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A test chapter}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{A test floating figure}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
\caption{A test non-floating figure}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This should be mentioned in the documentation of `float`. On the other hand, the `[H]` specifier should never be used. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg Yes, this should be mentioned in the documentation. I also agree that `[H]` shouldn't be used.