# How to tell LaTeX to place all figures at the end of pdf file?

Tags: floats, positioning

Well, I search through the SE site but it seems everyone else was asking how to avoid appending figure and their accidents are not quite an elegant solution to my problem --- I'm looking for a way (one line command if possible) so that I can either keep the figures where they appear within the text, or sweep all to the very end of file (after all text including bibliography) while maintaining their relative order. Any ideas?

Comment: I just had to do this and physically moved the code. For some reason, it didn't occur to me to search for a better solution. That said, what I needed was all *tables* moved, which I think means anything tabular-like. Mine happened to be a figure, though.

Comment: @cfr You could have used `\usepackage[nomarkers,tablesonly]{endfloat}`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks but I think your answer would work better because I actually have `\begin{figure}\begin{tabular}...` and I don't have any non-tabular figures. So I think your answer would move everything to the end correctly. (The system won't accept my .tex file anyway so I didn't actually get anywhere by moving anything. Hence maybe I'll try your solution and move the thing back after getting (hopefully) some instructions.)

Comment: I wonder anyone could ever have problem with this. I'm trying to get LaTeX **stop** putting all the images at the end of the document.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

For the first (risky (see link below)) possibility (force all figures to appear exactly where they are declared in the code, suppressing flotation), you can use the [`float`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/float) package and its `\floatplacement` command together with the `H` specifier:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{float}
\floatplacement{figure}{H}

\begin{document}
<contents>
\end{document}
```

Of course, this has some drawbacks: [Drawbacks of the `H` specifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161397/3954).

For the second one (moving all figures to the end of the document), the [`endfloat`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/endfloat) package can be used. For example, the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nomarkers,figuresonly]{endfloat}

\begin{document}
<contents>
\end{document}
```

will cause just `figure` environments (nor `table` or other user-defined floats) to be placed at the end of the document and won't produce any marker in the place where the figures originally were.

Refer to the package documentation to see all the other options it offers.

Comment: The `endfloat` package seems like the way to go, but it reports errors like this `AED endfloat: Processing end Figures and Tables
! Undefined control sequence.
\@enddocumenthook ...igures and Tables}\onecolumn
                                                  \processdelayedfloats
l.638 \end{document}` after I put it in one of the documents I have. No idea how to debug this...

Comment: @nye17 reduce the code to a minimal document reproducing the error and open a fresh new question posting there the offending minimal code.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks! Any obvious/easy way to force the figures to be resized to fit automatically? Some of mine appear too big to see the whole figure and caption when I use your endfloat line.

Answer (score 6):

There is also the [figcaps](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/figcaps) package, which has two simple switches to forward all floats to the end in `\figcapson` (enabled by default) and `\figcapsoff`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[printfigures]{figcaps} % printfigures to display figure floats
%\figcapsoff % enable to keep floats in their positions 

\begin{document}
<contents>
\end{document}
```

Do note that `figcaps` comes with far fewer options than `endfloat` and there seems to be no (easy) way to prevent it from printing the figure captions in addition to the figures themselves if you don't want them.

Comment: Thank you for this solution. For the record, @GonzaloMedina's solution moves only the figures in the end of the document, where this also moves the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Neither `figcaps` nor `endFloat` work for me as intended, because some of my pictures are in landscape mode and I would like to separate between figures in the body and appendix.

Altougt a bit verbose, this workaround works quite nicely, but happy to hear if there is a handier way to do this.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}


\usepackage{blindtext} % lorem ipsum
\usepackage{chngcntr} % for renumbering appendix 
\usepackage{comment}  % for choosing placement of figure in text (W for the "work-in-progress" and S for "submit" version)

\usepackage{pdflscape}      %adds PDF support to the landscape environment of package lscape
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{flafter} % no figures before section headings

% creating a conditional
\newif\ifS

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% set this to false if you want the figures in the text
% and to true if you want them at the end (S stands for "submit")

\Strue % \Sfalse or \Strue
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%this tells the comment-package which parts to include and exclude
\ifS
    \includecomment{S}
    \excludecomment{W}
\else
    \excludecomment{S}
    \includecomment{W}
\fi

%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\section{Intro}

% define figure1
\newcommand{\figureA}{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
\caption{figureA}
\label{fig:figureA}
\end{figure}
}

%place figure1 if this is the the work-in-progress (W) version
\begin{W}
\figureA
\end{W}

%define figure2
\newcommand{\figureB}{
\begin{landscape}\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-B}
\caption{figureB} 
\label{fig:figureB}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
}

%place figure 2 if the work-in-progress (W) version
\begin{W}
\figureB
\end{W}

\Blindtext % lorem ipsum

%-----------------------------------------------
% When it is time to submit and you want your figures at the end, you can place your figures & tables at the end, but before appendix.
% Remember that this controlled by \Strue & \Sfalse in the preabmle

\cleardoublepage

\begin{S}
\listoffigures
\figureA
\figureB
\end{S}

%------------------------------------------
\cleardoublepage
\appendix
\counterwithin{figure}{section} 
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\section{Appendix}\label{appendix}



\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image-golden}
\caption{Golden}
\label{fig:Golden}
\end{figure}



\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-grid-100x100pt}
\caption{Grid}
\label{fig:Grid}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```