# Including macros in texcount by regular expression

Tags: macros, floats, texcount

I would like to include all macros (or \newcommand's) that start with \figure and count them as floats in texcount. For context, [have a look in here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616389/244928).

It works if I tell texcount to increment the float counter individually for each \newcommand:

```
%TC:macroword \figureMyNthPicture [float]
```

It would be convenient that each newcommand that would start with a string, like \figure, would be counted and the `macrocount/macroword` would only need to be defined once.

I have tried the following regex without success:

```
%TC:macroword ^\\figure [float]
```

Below is a `MWE` that works, but the `macrocount/macroword` is currently defined individually for every macro, which is undesired.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{graphicx}
%---------------------------------------
\begin{document}


% define figureA
\newcommand{\figureA}{
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-a} 
\end{figure}
}

%Count figure A in texcount
%TC:macroword \figureA [float]

%place figureA
\figureA


%define figureB
\newcommand{\figureB}{
\begin{figure}[!htb]
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-B}
\end{figure}
}

%Count figure B in texcount
%TC:macroword \figureB [float]

%place figure B
\figureB


\end{document}
```

Comment: While it may convenient to have a regexp instead of the macro name, the program `texcount` cannot easily be tweaked to work with it. To select the rule to apply, the internal data structures use the macro name as a key to a lookup table. One would have to rewrite considerable parts of `texcount` to allow for the processing of regexps.

Answer (score 3):

beware adding spurious white space from macros (there are missing `%` here) but rather than use lots of macros using a naming convention why not use a single macro with an argument so `\myfigure{A}`  and `\myfigure{B}` ?

Then you only need to tell texcount about `\myfigure` you can define it as

```
\newcommand\myfigure[1]{\csname figure#1\endcsname}
```

and it will work with your existing defintions.