# How to place two figures side by side in multicol

Tags: positioning, subfloats, multicol

I would like to place two figures side by side in two column environment (Both figures fitting withing a single column)
I have read the answers but it's not working for me. The figure is placed on the next page.

ME:

```
   \documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \columnsep=100pt 
   \columnseprule=3pt 
   \usepackage[czech, english]{babel}
   \usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
   \usepackage{palatino} % Uncomment to use the Palatino font
   \usepackage{subfig}
   \usepackage{graphicx} 
   \graphicspath{{figures/}} % Location of the graphics files
   \usepackage{booktabs} % Top and bottom rules for table
   \usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
   \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
   \usepackage{wrapfig} % Allows wrapping text around tables and figures
   \usepackage{lipsum}

   \begin{document}
   \title{Morphological key at Afrilex 2014} % Poster

   \begin{multicols}{2} 
   \section*{Introduction - Icelandic and Czech?}
   \lipsum[3-6]
  \begin{figure*}[b!]
  \centering

  \subfloat[Market revenue]{%
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{online_dict2.png}%
  \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}%
  }\qquad
  \subfloat[Average price]{%
  \includegraphics[width=10cm]{online_dict2.png}%
  \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}%
  }

  \caption{Simulation results}
  \end{figure*}

  \subsection*{Types of Media}
  \end{multicols}
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Put the float at the beginning  (after `\maketitle`, `\title` only do nothing...) or after `multicols` environment with `[h]`.

Comment: I need to place the float (severel floats) inside multicols environment.

Comment: Are you interested in having the two figures span the entire page (one figure per column) or both figures fitting within a single column?

Comment: Both figures fitting withing a single column.

Comment: This might work. Do not use the figure environment. Directly use `includegraphics`. For captions, use the `caption` package

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can place the figures inside a `minipage` of width `\columnwidth` (and no indent):

[image]

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
\usepackage{multicol}
\columnsep=100pt 
\columnseprule=3pt 
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{Morphological key at Afrilex 2014} % Poster

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2} 
  \section*{Introduction - Icelandic and Czech?}
  \lipsum[3-6]

  \noindent
  \begin{minipage}{\columnwidth}
    \makeatletter
    \newcommand{\@captype}{figure}
    \makeatother
    \centering
    \subfloat[Market revenue]{%
      \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-a}%
      \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}%
    }\qquad%
    \subfloat[Average price]{%
      \includegraphics[width=10cm]{example-image-b}%
      \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}%
    }
    \caption{Simulation results}
  \end{minipage}

  \subsection*{Types of Media}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Since `\subfloat`s require to know which float environment they're in, setting the `\@captype` explicitly is necessary. [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) provides `\captionof{<type>}{<caption>}`, but it doesn't help for `\subfloat`.

Comment: Some people also might suggest using the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and supply an `[H]` float specifier. In this and the above case, you may have to adjust for the spacing with respect to the surrounding text. See [Drawbacks of the `H` specifier](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161397/5764)

Comment: I am sorry for late bounty awarding - I thought I have already done it. Thank you for help.

Comment: What if you need just two separate captions instead of one caption and two subcaptions?

Comment: @mmj: Do you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XPLp.png)?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: @mmj: [Here is the code](https://pastebin.com/raw/UMJCaK0x); nested `minipage`s separated with `\hfill`.

Comment: Thanks. Starting from your code I tried to add some features and ended up in posting a new question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/601485/28685

Answer (score 2):

Since `multicols` does not allow float environments, this proposal defines a new environment called `figurehere`. As you can see, the floating property is suppressed and it anchors at where one desires. This environment has been tested on `subcaptionbox` command from `subcaption` package (first image) and  `subfloat` command from `subfig` package (second image). They are all included in the code.

```
\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatother
```

[image: subcaptionbox]

Code

```
\documentclass[a0,portrait]{a0poster}
   \usepackage{standalone}
   \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
   \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{multicol}
   \columnsep=100pt 
   \columnseprule=3pt 
   \usepackage{palatino} 
%   \usepackage{subfig}       % for subfloat
   \usepackage{subcaption}% for subcaptionbox
   \usepackage{graphicx} 
   \usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amsthm, amssymb} 
   \usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{figurehere}
{\def\@captype{figure}}
{}
\makeatother

\captionsetup{labelfont=it,textfont={bf,it},justification=centering}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alph{subfigure}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure} }

\begin{document}


\title{Morphological key at Afrilex 2014} % Poster
\author{Author}
\maketitle

\begin{multicols}{2} 
\section*{Introduction - Icelandic and Czech?}
\lipsum[3-6]

% to run this session, please disable `sufig` package and enable `subcaption` package

\subsection*{Subcaptionbox section}

\begin{figurehere}
 \centering
  \subcaptionbox{Market revenue  \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-a}}\quad
  \subcaptionbox{Average price  \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}}{%
  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-b} }
  \caption{Simulation results}\label{Fig}
\end{figurehere}


% to run this session, please disable `subcaption` package and enable `subfig` package

%\subsection*{Subfloat section}
%
%\begin{figurehere}
% \centering
%\captionsetup{justification=centering}
%  \subfloat[Market revenue]{%
%  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-a}
%  \label{fig:evaluation:revenue}
%}\quad
%  \subfloat[Average price]{%
%  \includegraphics[width=0.45\columnwidth]{example-image-b}
%  \label{fig:evaluation:avgPrice}
%}
%  \caption{Simulation results,\label{Fig}}
%\end{figurehere}
%

\subsection*{Types of Media}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image: subfloat]