# Algorithm keeps appearing on the last page of my latex document

Tags: algorithms, algorithmic

I am writing an algorithm with the algorithmic environment and Latex keeps pushing it on the last page, no matter what I do, this is just a short example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt, twoside]{book}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[h]
\caption{my algorithm}
\label{alg:example}
\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE \REQUIRE \(F, G, j\)
\STATE \(B_{1} = \{b_{1}[1],\dots,b_{1}[|g_r|]\}\)
\STATE \(B_{1}\)
\FOR{\(i=1\) \TO \(n\)}
\STATE DO smoething...
 \STATE  
\ENDFOR
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
 \end{document}
```

The problem is that the algorithm is one page long, so I tried to put the h argument, and then after the algorithm a \newpage, so that everything else comes after it. But still it just ignores all my command and puts in on the last page, no matter what I try :S

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Obviously `algorithm` is an environment with floating enabled.

Comment: What Christian means is that you shouldn't specify `h` in the optional argument of the `algorithm` environment. Let that environment "float".

Comment: @Jubobs: Yes, I was too quick ;-) More over, the code does not compile at all

Comment: Ok sorry for putting an uncompilable code there, I just tried to copy as fast as possible a short example. my fault. Oh wow it worked... But isn't figure also an floating environment, because I-ve seen a lot of examples using the htb arguments for figures?

Comment: `[h]` tells latex the float isn't allowed at the top of a page (as no `t`) or bottom (no `b`) or on a page of floats (no `p`) which gives latex very few places to place it so holding it to the end is quite likely

Comment: Hmm ok never thought about that that way. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 1):

Replace `\begin{algorithm}[h]` by `\begin{algorithm}[H]` in your code.

It would place the float precisely (instead of approximately) at the location in the LATEX code. See [float specifiers](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures).

Note that there are some drawbacks may appear when use [H] specifier [Drawbacks of the [H] specifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/161397/drawbacks-of-the-h-specifier). However, it works without any problems in my code (which is too long to attach here, according to the nature of the problem).

Alternatively, the specifier [!htbp] works also and without wasting any page area before the algorithm position.

Both specifiers works in my code without any errors.

Comment: `[!]` will only work by coincident because `!` is on it's own no valid option for the floating specifier and will issue a warning and be replaced with the default option `!htbp`

Comment: According to [this blog](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Positioning_of_Figures), it works on determining "good" float positions. It did not issue a warning in my code, and I searched for what is possible problems associated with [!] and did not find there would be any warning issues.

Comment: `!` can only be used in combination with other floating specifier, such as h, t, b or p, not on its own. You'll get a warning with `LaTeX Warning: No positions in optional float specifier.
               Default added (so using !htbp) on input line 8.`

Comment: Yes, you are right. I just found this warning. However, the pdf is generated as required.

Comment: As the warning tells you, the missing arguments are replaced with the default ones, that's why the pdf is generated as it should. So instead of suggesting to use `[!]` in your answer, it might be better to suggest `[!htbp]` because this is the configuration which is actually used.

Comment: Ok,I examined it on my code and edited the answer!