# Placement of table in IEEE paper

Tags: tables, ieeetran

I am trying to create a table in the IEEE conference paper that I am writing. The table is after two 2 para but when I typeset, it goes in the top the colum!
I cant understand why this is happening. I am writing this like below:

```
text.....
text...
text...

\begin{table}[!t]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\caption{A Simple Example Table}
\label{table_example}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c||c}
\hline
\bfseries First & \bfseries Next\\
\hline\hline
1.0 & 2.0\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

text...
```

But the table goes above the text! Also, there should be two lines like:

```
       Table 1
A SIMPLE EXAMPLE TABLE
```

but for my case it prints in a single line. Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consider not changing any of the layout when submitting a paper. If tables should float to the top based on the conference paper class, then so-be-it.

However, you can force the floating behaviour of the `table` environment to stop based on the following two approaches:

1. Use the [`float` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) and the accompanying `[H]` float specifier.

   ```
   \usepackage{float}

   ...

   \begin{table}[H]
     \caption{A Simple Example Table}
     ...
   \end{table}
   ```

   If this is your choice, consider reading:

   - [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/5764)
   - [Drawbacks of the `H` specifier](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161397/5764)
2. Manually set a block that contains the table:

   ```
   \usepackage{capt-of}

   ...

   \noindent
   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
     \addvspace{\floatsep}% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/36362/5764

     \captionof{table}{A Simple Example Table}
     ...

     \addvspace{\floatsep}%
   \end{minipage}
   ```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Can u please give a solution about the title issue. why its typesetting in one line instead of two lines as it shows in the demo IEEE paper?! thanks again.

Comment: @dont_give_up: You may be using a specific option with the `\documentclass[..]{ieeetran}`.